# Encrypted Password become changing in appserver

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I'm sending request body as
grant_type=password&username=username&password=7LQCz+ACVLqJYjR39MjVTQ==
from mobile app

but password is taking as 7LQCz ACVLqJYjR39MjVTQ==

Comment: Well this tell me that you using a GET call. URL based body?

Comment: URLs generally take + as space, so for it to pass through the call you'll have to escape the actual significance of + i.e space. Replace the + with '%2B' for every plus.

Comment: I'm using POST call.

Comment: @PradumnKumarMahanta I replaced it but it again will be same.

Answer (score 0):

The sending side is not URL encoding but the receiving side is URL decoding. Both sided need to agree in the used encodings.

I general it is not necessary to URL encode POST data.

Comment: Sorry Here I forgot to mention.I encoded  at sending side also.In this + will be encoded as %2B but on server side it showing as space only.